# Cassandra node goes down with java heap error

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

> WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,619 GCInspector.java (line
>   142) Heap is 0.892615008651467 full.  You may need to reduce memtable
>   and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest
>   memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at
>   threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this
>   automatically
>
> WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,633
>   StorageService.java (line 3600) Flushing CFS(Keyspace='OpsCenter',
>   ColumnFamily='rollups60') to relieve memory pressure  INFO
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,634 ColumnFamilyStore.java
>   (line 630) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-rollups60@573393486(240/4340
>   serialized/live bytes, 15 ops)
>
> ERROR [Thrift:46] 2013-11-04
>   22:51:06,621 CassandraDaemon.java (line 192) Exception in thread
>
> Thread[Thrift:46,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>     at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.write(TFramedTransport.java:146)
>     at
>   com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.write(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:390)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TBinaryProtocol.writeBinary(TBinaryProtocol.java:73)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column.write(Column.java:579)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ColumnOrSuperColumn.write(ColumnOrSuperColumn.java:554)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_slice_result.write(Cassandra.java:7900)
>     at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:34)
>     at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:201)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  INFO
>   [FlushWriter:20] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,635 Memtable.java (line 495)
>   Completed flushing
>   /data/OpsCenter/rollups60/OpsCenter-rollups60-ic-889-Data.db (519
>   bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1383597360912,
>   position=10472305)
>
> INFO [FlushWriter:20] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,639
>   Memtable.java (line 461) Writing
>   Memtable-rollups300@1479174915(288/5560 serialized/live bytes, 12 ops)
>
> INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,683 Server.java
>   (line 160) Stop listening for CQL clients  INFO
>   [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2013-11-04 22:51:06,684 Gossiper.java
>   (line 1108) Announcing shutdown

When the compaction is going on my node dies. I have max_heap_size of 8G but still I don't how to configure my heap size.

Comment: How much memory (RAM) does the machine that C* is running on have and when you start cassandra what is `-Xmx` set to? (You can find out by simply starting cassandra in the foreground and checking the parameters).

Comment: I found this with ps command:-Xms8059M -Xmx8059M -Xmn400M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k -

Comment: free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32238      16487      15750          0        429       6112
-/+ buffers/cache:       9945      22293
Swap:          511          0        511
Total:       32750      16487      16262

Comment: It has 32GB of memory

Comment: Cassandra 1.2.6.1 & dse 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be too many prepared statements being cached (resolved in 1.2.11), view [CASSANDRA-6107](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6107). There was a hardcoded limit for the number of prepared statements that could be stored, but if the statement itself was large and enough of them were cached this would lead to high memory consumption, and since the statements were stored in a cache and never evicted from said cache GC wouldn't get rid of them. The fix was to make the cache's limit be a percentage of the total available memory and to avoid caching prepared statements that exceeded the max threshold.

However, after saying that, many things could lead to high memory consumption including:

- Bloom filter(s) size (moved off heap in C* 2.0 and later)
- Key cache
- Row cache (if turned on)
- Memtable size (or not flushing memtables frequrently enough)